# How to start with 2 rows in a dynamically table

Tags: angular

I am creating some rows dynamically but I want to know how can I start my table with two tables on the onInit.

You can see how the table works here:

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qbftdx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: Hi! what do you mean by "start table with two tables" ?

Answer (score 0):

You could just call AddDetails two times in your ngOnInit()...

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.AddDetails();
    this.AddDetails();
  }
```